Redshift Copy Command & parse to JSON
I'm trying to load data from S3 to Redshift using the COPY command.
The table where I'm trying to load have multiple columns, one of those is SUPER. I want to load JSON in that column.
For this example lets say the table is:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT,
  properties SUPER
);

This is the command I'm using to load the data
COPY my_table ("id","properties")
FROM 's3://.....'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...'
region 'us-east-1'
ACCEPTANYDATE
ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '~'
ENCODING UTF8
ROUNDEC
DATEFORMAT AS 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
COMPUPDATE OFF
STATUPDATE OFF
TRUNCATECOLUMNS
BLANKSASNULL
EMPTYASNULL
TRIMBLANKS
JSON 'auto'
GZIP
;

When I'm trying to load the data from S3 I'm getting this error
String value exceeds the max size of 65535 bytes                                                    

One of the JSON I'm trying to load have a properties value too long.
Example:
{
id: 123,
properties: '{\"Is Active\":true,\"Tags\":[\"TAG1\"....}'#longer than 65535 bytes
}

I tried to load the value into the table manually and it worked
INSERT INTO my_table ("id", "properties")
VALUES(123, JSON_PARSE('{\"Is Active\":true,\"Tags\":[\"TAG1\"....}'))

As you can see in the COPY Command I'm using the TRUNCATECOLUMNS property.
My understanding is the COPY command understands the properties value is a VARCHAR, and is not parsing it to JSON.
I'm wandering if there is a way to force the copy command to parse a column to JSON, using JSON_PARSE or if there is any other solution to be able to load the properties data into the SUPER column.

First off TRUNCATECOLUMNS is a COPY property that only applies to CHAR and VARCHAR data types.  So that can only help you if you are COPYing into a max VARCHAR and then converting this text into a SUPER if the text is valid JSON.  Possible solution except the too large strings will not be valid JSON.
Next you JSON looks wonky.  I'm not sure this is what your data really is in the S3 file(s) or if this is an artifact of how you are displaying it here.  In general single quotes are not valid and your keys need to be in double quotes.  Your files should look like:
{
    "id": 1006410,
    "title": "Amazon Redshift Database Developer Guide"
}
{
    "id": 100540,
    "name": "Amazon Simple Storage Service User Guide"
}

The data in the JSON file isn't formatted the same as what you pass to JSON_PARSE.  This looks wonky but it may be just how you added it to this question.
Also you shouldn't need the backslashes on the double quotes.  I expect they are being ignored in your working case.
I expect you are getting properties as a single string not as a nested object which is leading to the string too large error.
